# How to Serialize and De Serialize Hessian Calls in C

Tags: c, serialization, deserialization, hessian

For developing the Hessian client in Java hessian client libraries are available (hessian-3.x.x.jar) using that we can easily call Hessian service

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/communication-service";
HessianProxyFactory factory = new HessianProxyFactory();
final CommunicationService basic = (CommunicationService) factory.create(CommunicationService.class, url);
...
resultLabel.setText(basic.communicate(field.getText()));
```

For developing the Hessian client in C , how to serialize and de-serialize the hessian post and responses , Is there any opensource libraries available ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use [tpl](http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/index.html) library for serialization.